# How to use call() with prototypes?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

My goal is to add properties to the (this) context of a *Main* function from the prototype of an other function *Submain*

```
function Main() {
   Submain.call(this);
   //from here I want to be able to use this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d
   //...Main code...
}

function Submain() {
   //this works fine
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = 2;

   //this does not work because of the context
   this.doThis();
}

Submain.prototype.doThis = function() {
   this.c = 3;
   this.d = 4;
}
```

So, how to use the *Submain* prototype for this purpose ?

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I don't know what sort of solution you were hoping for. The object you provided doesn't have that method. You could manually put it there inside `Main` or on `Main.prototype`, but that doesn't seem very nice. Is there a particular reason you've arranged your code this way?

Comment: You can add doThing method instead of using prototyping. But is a bad choice (performance impact with many objects).
The better choice could be copy the Main prototype from Submain prototype
[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to understand better how the prototyping chain works

Comment: In fact, my Main prototype is huge, so I would like to cut it into several files to be more modular. I can use sub = new Submain() and then use sub.c, sub.d but I asked myself if there was an other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The part you are missing, if I understand correctly, is setting the `Main` constructor's prototype. This is how one would normally do it:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Main.prototype, Submain.prototype);
```

Then you could invoke `doThis` on objects created with `new Main` from within the constructor or from any other method:

```
var main = new Main();
console.log(main.c, main.d); // prints 3, 4
```

Comment: My general understand is that `setPrototypeOf` carries immense and difficult-to-track performance issues, even in trivial applications?

Comment: @furkle This is an urban legend from pre-ES6 times, but still popularized by MDN.

Comment: Really? Are there any papers on that? Because that'd be hugely useful to me if so; deserializing objects and re-adding prototype methods is a pain, but the language on MDN is... frightening.

Comment: @furkle Papers? Not that I know of. There are [some jsPerfs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Object.setPrototypeOf+site:https:%2F%2Fjsperf.com) comparing `Object.setPrototypeOf` to other methods. Maybe you could have a look there to overcome your worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to merge the *Submain* prototype to the *Main* prototype.

This can be done with **Object.assign** (ES6).

```
function Main() {}

Main.prototype = Object.assign(Submain.prototype, {
    doThat: function() {
        Submain.call(this);
        //from here I can use this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d
    },
    //...Main functions...
});

function Submain() {
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = 2;

   //this works now
   this.doThis();
}

Submain.prototype.doThis = function() {
   this.c = 3;
   this.d = 4;
}
```